# How convert color code to hex?

Tags: android

How to convert color code to code hex in android ? I am getting this color code from webservice, so i have to convert it to hex for my using it.

```
Ex:  0x59b512 -> #12b559
```

Thanks!

Comment: how you want to use it and where to use ? there may be another way.If you can say we can suggest.

Comment: One of those is likely RGB while another is BGR. This information is *important* to include in the post, as well as *where* the data comes from and *where* it will be used ..

Comment: i want .setBackgroundColor from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear. If you need to use hex coded colors in .xml files then, you need to create a set of styles in your xml (regularly in res/values/styles.xml). e.g.

```
<color name="gray">#eaeaea</color>
<color name="titlebackgroundcolor">#00abd7</color>
<color name="titlecolor">#666666</color>
```

In the layout files you can call to the colors or styles:

```
android:textColor="@color/titlecolor"
```

Comment if you've problems.

Edited: you can try to convert it into hex by using this:

```
String strColor = String.format("#%06X", Color);
```

Then use `strColor` to set your background.

Comment: But my webservice return 0x59b512. Now i wat set color from 0x59b512.

Comment: Do you need only masking from the color code obtained from android.graphics.Color to the #RRGGBB? @mum

Comment: But 0x59b512 is result of  type String.

Comment: Do you need only to convert from 0xRRGGBB to #RRGGBB? @mum